# Getting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 for .ttf and .woff files

Tags: html, node.js, icons, truetype, woff

I'm trying to display icon-fonts by using 4 files (  `.ttf`  / `.woff` / `.svg` / `.eot` ) and from a `Style.css`  but i'm getting the below error on my console :

```
GET http://localhost:9090/fonts/SAIP-Icons.ttf?unaq0q net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET http://localhost:9090/fonts/SAIP-Icons.woff?unaq0q net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I tried to add ( `app.use(express.static('fonts'));` ) in my .js file but i didn't work , not sure what's the issue here.

this is my project image  : 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG2SV.jpg)